# How do I insert a JavaScript variable into a string containing Jinja markup?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have a javascript function that is trying to dynamically insert an anchor tag into a webpage, the href attr of which being a url for a flask route. This flask route accepts an argument `username`. I want to set `username` to the value of a javascript variable.

I have tried using template literals:

```
let username = 'user1';
let href = `{{ url_for("some.route", username=${username}) }}`

$("#elem").append('<a href=' + href + '></a>');
```

which throws a `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '$'` error.

I've also tried string concatenation:

```
let username = 'user1';
let href = '{{ url_for("some.route", username=' + username + ')}}'

$("#elem").append('<a href=' + href + '></a>');
```

which results in the literal string `+ username +` being passed to the route.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I suppose it's not possible. Jinja2 templates execute on the server side rather than JS code executes on the client side (in the browser).

Comment: Why then if I hardcode a value into the `href` variable, eg. `let href = {{ url_for("some.route", username="bob") }}` does it work, given that there's a user called bob? This produces valid Jinja without reloading the page i.e. AFTER getting a response from the server